# Counting attribute values from CSV?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, count

I want to create a function that returns the count of each attribute value from a csv, the output should be a dictionary (for every attribute one) where the keys are the distinct attribute values and the associated values are the number of times that value occurs in the data...

for example I have the following CSV-File (the first line is the header):

```
First_Name,Last_Name,Age
Johnny,Got,22
Michael,Jackson,22
Johnny,Jackson,50
Andrea,Got,12
```

and I would wish to have that as output then,

```
for first name: {'Johnny': 2, 'Michael': 1, 'Andrea': 1}
for the second name: {'Jackson': 2, 'Got': 2}
and for the age: {22: 2, 50: 1, 12: 1}
```

I think I could do it with using the `Counter` class from the python `collections` module when I use the `DictReader` type for the CSV so that each row is a dictionary as well. But I still can't bring it to work, does anyone have an idea if that is possible? Here what I tried until now. `:)`

```
import csv
import os
import collections

FIRSTNAME_ATT = 'First_Name'
LASTNAME_ATT = 'Last_Name'
AGE_ATT = 'Age'


def count_attributes(file_name):
    firstname_counts = {}
    lastname_counts = {}
    age_counts = {}

    with open(file_name, encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        for row in reader:
            for i, val in enumerate(row):
                count_number[i][val] += 1
# Here I don't get any further :(
    return firstname_counts, lastname_counts, age_counts


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data_file = os.path.join("..", "data", "thecsvfile.csv")
    firstname_counts, lastname_counts, age_counts = attribute_counts(data_file)
    print(firstname_counts)
    print(lastname_counts)
    print(age_counts)
```

Would be great if anyone has an hint or an idea how to solve that. `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to `collections.Counter`, you could use a `collections.OrderedDict` to keep things simple plus make the processing largely "date-driven" in the sense that the contents of the csv file itself will determine what the attributes are (instead of hardcoding their names).

The use of `OrderedDict` preserves the order of the attributes in the csv file's header row.

Here's what I'm saying:

```
import os
import csv
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict

def count_attributes(file_name):
    with open(file_name, encoding='utf-8', newline='') as csv_file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        counters = OrderedDict((attr, Counter()) for attr in reader.fieldnames)
        for row in reader:
            for attr, value in row.items():
                counters[attr][value] += 1

    return counters

if __name__ == '__main__':
#    data_file = os.path.join("..", "data", "thecsvfile.csv")
    data_file = "thecsvfile.csv"  # Slight simplification for testing.
    for attr, counts in count_attributes(data_file).items():
        print('{}: {}'.format(attr.replace('_', ' '), dict(counts)))
```

Output:

```
First Name: {'Johnny': 2, 'Michael': 1, 'Andrea': 1}
Last Name: {'Got': 2, 'Jackson': 2}
Age: {'22': 2, '50': 1, '12': 1}
```

Comment: Sandra: That's good to hear...one of our aims here is to please. `;¬)`

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**:

```
firstname_counts = {}
lastname_counts = {}
age_counts = {}

with open(file_name, encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in reader:
        firstname_counts[row['First_Name']] = firstname_counts.get(row['First_Name'], 0) + 1
        lastname_counts[row['Last_Name']] = lastname_counts.get(row['Last_Name'], 0) + 1
        # similar for age...
```

You just need to check if the key in the dictionaries exist, if it does, add value 1 or get 0 when it does not exist and add 1. `.get` method 
 in dictionary solves it.

Ref: [dict .get method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

EDIT:

**Solution 2 (Using `collections.Counter`)**:

```
from collections import Counter

firstname_counts = Counter()
lastname_counts = Counter()
age_counts = Counter()

# same code as in the above solution.
```

Comment: Is `0` is the fallback value here? `firstname_counts.get(row['First_Name'], 0)`

Comment: @bhansa Yes. It is the fallback (default) value, if the key does not exist in the `dict` object.

Comment: thanks for your reply! I wanted to use the Counter type from the python collections module because then it would be sorted by the value (attribute with highest number in first position), I guess I need to do it completely different then?